# How i can read this ram and return a q = 1 when two addresses have the same value

Tags: vhdl, ram

I have created this ram :

```
    library ieee;
        use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
        USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
        entity true_dpram_sclk is
        port 
        (   
        data_a  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        data_b  : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        address_a   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        address_b   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        we_a    : in std_logic := '1';
        --  we_b    : in std_logic := '1';
        clk     : in std_logic;
        q_a     : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        q_b     : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        q           : out std_logic
        );

        end true_dpram_sclk;

        architecture rtl of true_dpram_sclk is

        -- Build a 2-D array type for the RAM
        subtype word_t is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        type memory_t is array(17 downto 0) of word_t;

        -- Declare the RAM
        shared variable ram : memory_t;
        SIGNAL ADDR_A : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 17;
        SIGNAL ADDR_B : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 17;

        begin

        -- Port A
        process(clk)
        begin
        ADDR_A<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_A);
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then 
            if(we_a = '1') then
                ram(addr_a) := data_a;
            elsif (we_a = '0') then
                q_a <= ram(addr_a);
            else
                q_a <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
            end if;
        end if; 
        end process;

        -- Port B
        process(clk)
        begin
        ADDR_B<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_B);
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(we_a = '1') then
                ram(addr_b) := data_b;
            elsif (we_a = '0') then
                q_b <= ram(addr_b);
            else
                q_b <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
            end if;
        end if; 
        end process;

        --   --MATCHER
        --  process (clk)
        --  begin
        --       if ((we_a = '0') and (we_b = '0') and ram(addr_a) = 
        --ram(addr_b)) then
        --                  q <= '1';
        --          else
        --                  q <= '0';
--   end if;        
--  end process;
--
end rtl;
```

And also the above test benchmark:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY tb2 IS
END tb2;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb2 IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT true_dpram_sclk
    PORT(
         data_a : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         data_b : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         address_a : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         address_b : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         we_a : IN  std_logic;
    --     we_b : IN  std_logic;
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         q_a : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         q_b : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            q : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

--   COMPONENT matcher
--   PORT(
--          A : IN std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
--          B : IN std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
--          clk: IN std_logic;
--          Q : OUT std_logic
--          );
--   END COMPONENT;     

   --Inputs
   signal data_a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal data_b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal address_a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal address_b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal we_a : std_logic := '1';
 --  signal we_b : std_logic := '1';
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL ADDR_A : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 17;
    SIGNAL ADDR_B : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 17;

    --Outputs
   signal q_a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal q_b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal q : std_logic := '0';

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: true_dpram_sclk PORT MAP (
          data_a => data_a,
          data_b => data_b,
          address_a => address_a,
          address_b => address_b,
          we_a => we_a,
   --       we_b => we_b,
          clk => clk,
          q_a => q_a,
          q_b => q_b,
             q => q
        );

--  uut: matcher PORT MAP (
--          A => q_a,
--           B => q_b,
--           clk => clk,
--           Q => Q
--        );      

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period;
    end process;

process
begin
    --Write data into RAM
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --1
        address_a <= "00000000";
        address_b <= "00000000";
        data_a <= "10111001";
        data_b <= "10111001";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --2
        address_a <= "00000001";
        address_b <= "00000001";
        data_a <= "01101100";
        data_b <= "01101100";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --3
        address_a <= "00000010";
        address_b <= "00000010";
        data_a <= "00110011";
        data_b <= "00110011";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --4
        address_a <= "00000011";
        address_b <= "00000011";
        data_a <= "00001101";
        data_b <= "00001101";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --5
        address_a <= "00000100";
        address_b <= "00000100";
        data_a <= "00001010";
        data_b <= "00001010";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --6
        address_a <= "00000101";
        address_b <= "00000101";
        data_a <= "00110111";
        data_b <= "00110111";
        wait for clk_period*1;
       --7
        address_a <= "00000110";
        address_b <= "00000110";
        data_a <= "11110010";
        data_b <= "10111001";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --8
        address_a <= "00000111";
        address_b <= "00000111";
        data_a <= "10101011";
        data_b <= "01101100";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --9
        address_a <= "00001000";
        address_b <= "00001000";
        data_a <= "01111000";
        data_b <= "00110011";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --10
        address_a <= "00001001";
        address_b <= "00001001";
        data_a <= "01011000";
        data_b <= "00001101";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --11
        address_a <= "00001010";
        address_b <= "00001010";
        data_a <= "00001010";
        data_b <= "00001010";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --12
        address_a <= "00001011";
        address_b <= "00001011";
        data_a <= "00111000";
        data_b <= "00110111";
    wait for clk_period*1;

   --Read data from RAM
    we_a <= '0';
--  we_b <= '0';

        --1
        address_a <= "00000000";
        address_b <= "00000000";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --2
        address_a <= "00000001";
        address_b <= "00000001";
        wait for clk_period*1;
       --3
        address_a <= "00000010";
        address_b <= "00000010";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --4
        address_a <= "00000011";
        address_b <= "00000011";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --5
        address_a <= "00000100";
        address_b <= "00000100";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --6
        address_a <= "00000101";
        address_b <= "00000101";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --7
        address_a <= "00000110";
        address_b <= "00000110";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --8
        address_a <= "00000111";
        address_b <= "00000111";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --9
        address_a <= "00001000";
        address_b <= "00001000";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --10
        address_a <= "00001001";
        address_b <= "00001001";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --11
        address_a <= "00001010";
        address_b <= "00001010";
        wait for clk_period*1;
        --12
        address_a <= "00001100";
        address_b <= "00001100";
        wait for clk_period*1;

wait;
end process;

END behavior;
```

I want to read the address_a and address_b and compare them one by one and return q <= '1' when the address_a = adress_b and q <= '0' when is not equal. I Want something like this:

```
--Read data from RAM
    we_a <= '0';
--  we_b <= '0';

        --1
        address_a <= "00000000";
        address_b <= "00000000";
        if ( q_a = q_b ) then 
        q <= '1'; else
        q <= '0';
        end if;
        wait for clk_period*1;
```

Any help it will be great. Thank you!!

Comment: Provide a minimal example.

Comment: I have edit my post you can check it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Choice of library

```
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

Faux pas. That is a not standardized library. Don't use it. Replace it with

```
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
```

And use the `UNSIGNED` or `SIGNED` data types for arithmetic.

And especially don't use these two libraries at the same time, like you are doing in your test bench...

---

### Size mismatch

```
address_a   : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
[...]
SIGNAL ADDR_A : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 17;
[...]
ADDR_A<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_A);
```

`address_a` is 8 bit, thus has a range of 0 to 255 (or -128 to 127 if it's signed). You cannot simply put that in a range 0 to 17 signal. This can cause an error.

---

### Sequential versus combinatorial

```
-- Port A
process(clk)
begin
    ADDR_A<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_A);
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
```

The assignment `ADDR_A<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_A);` is a combinatorial statement. Yet you put it in the clocked process (but not in the clocked if-statement). This has all kind of strange effects, especially when you synthesize: it will maybe even generate a latch.

`ADDR_A<=CONV_INTEGER(ADDRESS_A);` needs to be outside of the process. And even better is if you use library `numeric_std` and `ADDR_A <= to_integer(unsigned((ADDRESS_A));`

---

### Unreachable code in implementation and incorrect RAM instantiation.

In implementation logic values can only be '0' and '1'.

```
if(we_a = '1') then
    [...]
elsif (we_a = '0') then
    [... we_a = '0' is redundant here ...]
else
    [... unreachable, as '1' and '0' are already covered ...]
end if;
```

Thus sufficient is:

```
if(we_a = '1') then
    ram(addr_b) := data_b;
else
    q_b <= ram(addr_b);
end if;
```

This is not properly supported RAM coding however, because you are typing to stop `q_b` from changing when `we_a = '1'`. Correct would be:

```
q_b <= ram(addr_b);
if(we_a = '1') then
    ram(addr_b) := data_b;
end if;
```

I.e. `q_b` will also change when you write.
Refer to the [Xilinx synthesis user guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) for instance.

---

### Accessing the RAM data

A block RAM (like you intend to use) is a closed component. It only has a maximum of two access ports, which you are both using: Port A and Port B. However, in your third process you attempt to access the RAM through a third port!

```
if [...] ram(addr_a) = ram(addr_b) [...] then
```

That is not possible.

If you want to compare the values at the addresses, you will have to fetch them from the RAM first... which will actually already happens in the Port A and Port B processes (if you correctly change these like I previously suggested). You can then simply compare the contents using:

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if q_a = q_b then
            q <= '1';
        else
            q <= '0';
        end if;        
    end if;
end process;
```

---

### Question versus code??

In your code you are comparing the RAM *contents*

```
ram(addr_a) = ram(addr_b)
```

However, if I read your question, you want to compare the *addresses*.

```
addr_a = addr_b
```

What is it? If it's the latter, no need to do complicated stuff. Just do:

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if addr_a = addr_b then
            q <= '1';
        else
            q <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: In last part i want to compare the ram(addr_a) = ram(addr_b).Thank you for all the information i will appreciate it so much!!

Comment: @georgek please read my edit. I made some mistakes, missing the if statement for the clocked process.